# How do I make builds public in buildbot

Tags: buildbot

I have a buildbot working and have added basic authentication following "Setting Authorized Web Users" from the manual http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/tour.html. I was hoping to restrict people who could trigger a new build.

But now the web interface shows no builds at all without login. How can I make the builds public?

My current config looks like this, minus the line giving the password details.

```
c['www']['authz'] = util.Authz(
        allowRules = [
                        util.AnyControlEndpointMatcher(role="admins")
                    ],
        roleMatchers = [
                        util.RolesFromUsername(roles=['admins'], usernames=['xxx'])
                    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure authentication and authorization.

Probably the simple example config is enough for your simple example
http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-www.html#example-configs

Comment: I have tried to copy this simple example (details added above).

Comment: The simple example does not make sense to me. I cannot see which part of it opens access to public. Unless it is the `AnyControlEndpointMatcher` part, which I have tried and does not appear to achieve what I want.

Comment: Something strange is up. I have replicated this on two machines now. In both cases, with login, I can see build. As "Anonymous" all I can see "waterfall", "console" and "builds" not they are empty; always "0 builds". Not sure where to debug from here.

Comment: The simple example works for me. The default is open access to anyone, and the `AnyControlEndpointMatcher` matches the force build/cancel build etc endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I have crated a solution based on this message to the mailing list.

https://lists.buildbot.net/pipermail/users/2017-February/001066.html

```
##util.AnyControlEndpointMatcher(role="admins")

util.StopBuildEndpointMatcher(role="admins"),
util.ForceBuildEndpointMatcher(role="admins"),
util.RebuildBuildEndpointMatcher(role="admins")
```

This seems to run counter to the documentation which says a call to `AnyControlEndpointMatcher` should be added and the simple example. So still confused.